# How can I change mysql db query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, reactjs

The data which I would like to receive at the api endpoint is:

```
[
    {"Products":5,"Computer":2,"Handphone":3},
    {"Fruits":4,"Orange":2,"Apple":2},
    {"Consumables":6,"Tissue":2,"Wet Wipes":3, "Handkerchief":1}
]
```

So products category contains computer, handphone. Fruits category contain orange and apple. Consumables category contain tissue, wet wipes and handkerchief

I have the following data in mySQL:

| ID | Items | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Computer | Products |
| 2 | Handphone | Products |
| 3 | Computer | Products |
| 4 | Handphone | Products |
| 5 | Handphone | Products |
| 6 | Orange | Fruits |
| 7 | Orange | Fruits |
| 8 | Apple | Fruits |
| 9 | Apple | Fruits |
| 10 | Tissue | Consumables |
| 11 | Tissue | Consumables |
| 12 | Wet Wipes | Consumables |
| 13 | Wet Wipes | Consumables |
| 14 | Handkerchief | Consumables |
| 15 | Wet Wipes | Consumables |

This is the code I use to make my db query in react:

```
app.get("/countintents", (req, res) => {
  db.query(
    "SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN intent IN ('Products', 'Land Transport') THEN 1 END) AS products, SUM(CASE WHEN intent IN ('Air Freight', 'Industry Solutions', 'Aerospace and Defense') THEN 1 END) AS industry_solutions, SUM(CASE WHEN intent in ('Profile', 'Contact Us') THEN 1 END) AS about_us FROM data_analytics",
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.send(result);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

I would be asking what should my db query be?

Answer (score 0):

You can get group total in database query like below.

```
SELECT category, items, count_items FROM(
        select items, category, count(items) count_items
        from <your_table>
        group by items, category
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Category, Category, Count(category)
        from <your_table>
        GROUP BY Category
    ) X ORDER BY category,count_items.
```

I am checking for the Mysql JSON support like the result you need.

Comment: Ok I added the column in my question, If I don't have a category column can I still do it using ALIAS?

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the values using `group by with rollup`:

```
select category, item, count(*) as cnt
from t
group by category, item with rollup
having category is not null ;
```

You can construct separate rows with strings using string aggregation:

```
select group_concat(coalesce(item, category), ':', cnt order by (item is null) desc, item)
from (select category, item, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by category, item with rollup
      having category is not null
     ) ci
group by category;
```

Or as JSON arrays:

```
select json_arrayagg(json_object(coalesce(item, category), cnt))
from (select category, item, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by category, item with rollup
      having category is not null
     ) ci
group by category;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=23ea3d3c006fc2fdee92f50369f7db9c) is a db<>fiddle.